# Why is the standard error $\sigma/\sqrt{N}$ not considered as being as brilliant as $a^2+b^2=c^2, \pi, e$ etc.

Tags: statistics, soft-question, math-history

I'm aware that the standard error of mean is statistics. But what is the explanation that the standard error of mean $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ is not considered being as brilliant an invention as

- Pythagoras' theorem
- $\pi$
- $e$

etc.?

Unquestionably, in maths the above and others like $e = mc^{2}$ etc. are considered ground-breaking concepts.

$$\sigma/\sqrt{N}$$

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

1) generally use little "n" in statistics for sample size, big "N" is reserved to denote a normal distribution

2) This is extremely subjective

3) As a statistician, I don't think standard error is that incredible. For highly skewed data it becomes useless (i.e. standard error for mean of incomes) while for skewed data something like a five number summary are better statistics to report.

4) I'd argue if anything from statistics that would take a top echelon place would be the CLT or maybe simple "1.96"

Comment: +1, good answer. CLT is definitely top on my list